# Android App Dev - High CPU on simple actions

Tags: android, performance, cpu, lag

I am currently developing an app. The app can handle customers and orders. I recently wrote a little function that creates a dummy customer in case an order got no customer yet. Customer contains bitmap,name,url,email. When I use that simple function to create that customer and then navigate to the listview that holds all my customers (2 in total for example) then it laggs incredibly. I get like 2 FPS and everything takes like 5 secounds to load. When I create the very same customer in the app itself in a GUI that I created for that task, it runs smooth as it is supposed to run. I don't know where that could come from.

Here is the CPU trace where I click on "Customers" in the navigation drawer:
[image]
The code to create the customer via the app:

```
Bitmap icon = ((BitmapDrawable) customerImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

Customer customer =  new Customer(icon, name.getText().toString(), url.getText().toString(), email.getText().toString());
```

And the code where I create the customer directly in the MainActivity in the onCreate Function:

```
 public static Customer getEmptyCustomer(Activity act) {
        emptyCustomer  = new Customer(Utility.getIconEmpty(act),"-","-","-");
        return emptyCustomer;
    }
```

The code is super simple and straightforward. I don't know what other parts of the code might be important for that issue. Can't think of any.

Hope someone knows that behaviour and can help a little.

EDIT:

Customer class:

```
 public Customer(Bitmap logo, String name, String URL, String email) {
        this.logo = logo;
        this.name = name;
        this.URL = URL;
        this.email = email;

        // arrayListCustomers.add(this);

        addCustomer(this);
    }

    public Customer() {

    }

    // return 0 = everything good
    // return 1 = name already exists
    public int addCustomer(Customer c) {

        boolean alreadyExists = false;

        for (Customer customer : arrayListCustomers) {
            if (customer.name.equals(c.name)) {
                alreadyExists = true;
            }
        }

        if (!alreadyExists) {
            arrayListCustomers.add(c);
            FileManager.saveCustomerToSdCard(c);
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

And the FileManager functions:

```
 public static void saveCustomerToSdCard(Customer c) {

        String filename = c.name+".json";

        File customerDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Formicorn/Customer/");

        if (!customerDir.exists()) {
            if (!customerDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("App", "Failed to create customer directory");
            }
        }


        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(c);

        File file = new File(customerDir, filename);

        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
            writer.write(json);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        saveLogoToSdCard(c);

    }


private static void saveLogoToSdCard(Customer c) {

    String filename = "logo_"+c.name+".png";

    File logosDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Formicorn/Customer/Logos");

    if (!logosDir.exists()) {
        if (!logosDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("App", "Failed to create logo directory");
        } else {
            Log.d("App", "Successfully created logo directory");
        }
    }


    File logoFile = new File(logosDir, filename);

    boolean success = false;

    // Encode the file as a PNG image.
    FileOutputStream outStream;
    try {

        outStream = new FileOutputStream(logoFile);
        c.logo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
    /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */

        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        success = true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: How large is the `customerImage`? `android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw` spent most of the time. Did you use Background task for fetching data from network?

Comment: @Raptor Imagesize is 30kB. I do not use background tasks in this app.

Comment: You should consider to use background task to offload the loading

Comment: @Raptor I definitely will do that at some point. But first I need to solve this issue here. Do you think it is related?

Comment: Can you post the constructor of your `Customer` class as well?

Comment: @Raptor Added it to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the image is only 30kB its pixelsize is 1000x1000. Decreasing it to 200x200 pixels solved the problem. I still doubt, that the emulator is that weak or android can't handle that pixelsize. If anyone got additional thoughts to that, please share them.

Comment: Uncompressing an image of 30KB will consume more than 30KB RAM in runtime. In mobile devices, every MB of RAM is precious. See [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html) for further details.